# Comparator of a generic class

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have a generic class :

```
class Card<T extends Enum<T> & Rank> implements Comparable<Card<T>>
```

`Rank` is java interface. 
I'm trying to make a `Comparator` instance in the `Card` class.

```
public final static Comparator<Card> comparator = new Comparator<Card>() { ... }
```

The previous line has a warning.

> Card is a raw type. References to generic type Card should be
>   parameterized

How can I declare the generic type of the `Card` class ?

Comment: I'm...not seeing it from these slivers of code.  Which line of code are you getting this error?  (I'm willing to bet you declared an instance of `Card` without giving it a type.)

Comment: Does your comparator implementation require `T` to be any specific type (or extend a specific type)? If not, you should be fine with just `Comparator<Card<?>>`. On another note, why do you still need a comparator if you make `Card` already `Comparable`?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Thanks, your answer solved my problem. I need more than one different comparators for the same class.

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't let `Card` implement `Comparable`. If you ever forget to use a `Comparator` somewhere, it might use `Comparable.compareTo` instead and cause some very hard to find bugs. If you don't implement `Comparable`, forgetting a `Comparator` will cause a compiler error. ;-)

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Thank you for your advice. I will remove the implementation of the Comparable interface.

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis perhaps you could post your solution (with code) as an answer when you have it working.

Comment: just add parameter to your card `public final static Comparator<Card<?>> comparator = new Comparator<Card<?>>(){}`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Post this as an answer - it should get upvoted

Comment: @WilliamPrice I just posted the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Card<T extends Enum<T> & Rank> {

  private final T rank;
  private final Suit suit;

  public Card(T rank, Suit suit) 
  {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public final static <T extends Enum<T> & Rank> Comparator<Card<T>> byRank() 
  {
    return new Comparator<Card<T>>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Card<T> o1, Card<T> o2) 
      {
        int r = compareRank(o1, o2);
        return  r != 0 ? r : compareSuit(o1,o2); 
      }
    };
  }

  public final static <T extends Enum<T> & Rank> Comparator<Card<T>> bySuit() 
  {
    return new Comparator<Card<T>>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Card<T> o1, Card<T> o2) 
      {
        int r = compareSuit(o1,o2); 
        return r != 0 ? r : compareRank(o1, o2);
      }
    };
  }

}
```